# Run mongo 3.2.4 with --ssl parameter under Windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, ssl

I've downloaded MongoDB Community Edition for Windows from mongodb.org (Windows 64-bit 2008 R2+), and website says that this version has SSL support (there are alerts on other versions that say they haven't). I'm running Windows 10. From what I've understood, SSL is build in by default from version 3.0, and I'm running with an Ubuntu server a mongod Community Edition instance (64bit, 3.0.10) installed from repository that use SSL.

When I try to run mongo.exe on local Windows machine with --ssl parameter it says:

```
Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--ssl'
```

and others tools say that it doesn't support ssl.

I'm sure that on a previous setup I was running a 3.0.x mongo instance with SSL support on windows, I've tried also to install older versions, but nothing works.

My questions: are 3.0 and 3.2 community edition branches (still) compiled with SSL support on Windows, and if yes, why they doesn't work on my current setup? I'm sure they worked on previous one, may be a configuration problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the Downloads page links to the Non SSL bundle. The [Official Help page](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) indicates the installer file name is `mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.2.4-signed.msi` which is not the same as the one downloaded via Downloads page (`mongodb-win32-x86_64-3.2.4-signed.msi`). Get the SSL enabled installer from https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/x86_64-2008plus-ssl